# Oracle GTT in web application

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Does oracle GTT share same data between different users, who are logged into a website?.
My web application uses GTT data and the same data is available to another user logged into the same application.
I use oracle apex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GTT knows nothing about website and users. GTT stores data at per-session basis. If developer allows different users to share Oracle session - he should use adequate tools to prevent data mixing. It's [ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/statements_7002.htm#i2189569) option for GTTs and [pragma SERIALLY_REUSABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems046.htm) for packages.

Comment: That means it will work only if I create different db session for different users, isn't?